# Method 'PUT' in Snap

Tags: haskell-snap-framework

If I specify method="PUT" in a web form and also filter by this method in the route by giving

```
 ("/tickets/:id",      method PUT    updateTicket)
```

the form never gets to the handler.
The handler never even triggered. As soon as I change method to POST in the route and in the form then everything works as expected.

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try not limiting your route to a certain method.  Then you can do some debugging to see what's really going on:

```
updateTicket = do
    meth <- getsRequest rqMethod
    liftIO $ putStrLn $ "Request had method "++(show meth)
    ...
```

Then play around with your form and see what's actually happening.